# Как получить только последней сделки на ByBit API?

Tags: python

Работаю с bybit api, хочу получать цену только последний сделки, но как это сделать не разобрался.

Код:

```
    for i in range(60):
        a = session.get_index_price_kline(
                category="inverse",
                symbol="BTCUSDT",
                interval=1,
                start=1,
                end=10,
                limit=2,
        )
        print(a)
        sleep(0.5)
```

Вывод в консоль:

`{'retCode': 0, 'retMsg': 'OK', 'result': {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'category': 'inverse', 'list': [['1711180620000', '64507.94', '64586.49', '64507.94', '64586.49'], ['1711180560000', '64501.28', '64510.5', '64501.28', '64507.94']]}, 'retExtInfo': {}, 'time': 1711180669778}`

Пытался вызвать элемент со списка, но не получилось, скорее всего делал это не правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, оказалось всё легче простого, вот решение:

```
q = a['result']['list'][0][4]
super_style = float(''.join(map(str, q)))
```

Надо было создать лист и находить каждый элемент в словаре, дальше просто вызвать нужный элемент и лист преобразовать в тип данных float